# Auto height resize window jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Con el siguiente código selecciono los elementos para aplicarle como altura la misma del navegador; pero después, cuando dimensiono el tamaño del navegador, la altura no cambia.

```
function init_heght(element) {
    var y = $(window).height();
    $(element).css('height', y);
};

init_heght('#section-left-menu');
init_heght('#section-rigth-content');
init_heght('.overlay');
```

Answer (score 4):

No necesitas hacerlo con JavaScript, con CSS te basta:

```
#section-left-menu,
#section-right-content,
.overlay {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Aun así si quieres hacerlo con JavaScript, necesitar añadir un manejador al evento `resize` para que te actualice el alto de dichos elementos al redimensionar el viewport:

```
window.addEventlistener('resize', function () {
  init_height('#section-left-menu');
  init_height('#section-rigth-content');
  init_height('.overlay');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

También sería importante usar un temporizador https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize#setTimeout ya que es muy costosa la modificación del DOM.

```
(function() {

  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeThrottler, false);

  var resizeTimeout;
  function resizeThrottler() {
    // ignore resize events as long as an actualResizeHandler execution is in the queue
    if ( !resizeTimeout ) {
      resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        resizeTimeout = null;
        actualResizeHandler();

       // The actualResizeHandler will execute at a rate of 15fps
       }, 66);
    }
  }

  function actualResizeHandler() {
    // handle the resize event
    ...
  }

}());
```

Comment: Editado. @Mariano ¿Qué es lo que no entiendes? Sólo has de hacer scroll hacia arriba en el articulo y puedes leer la importancia de usar un temporizador

Comment: @manifiestoWeb me refiero a que, según mi opinión, y por más que esté en tu código, aún falta explicar la respuesta principal a la pregunta: que hay que asociar una función al evento window.resize... Y luego sí, está genial tu recomendación de usar un timer, pero que lo importante de ese timer es que se dispara sólo si no se creó otro timer previamente, acumulando así ejecuciones que podrían ser costosas